# I'm still on my probation period, but I don't feel that the job is right for me. Can I quit?

Tags: professionalism, new-job, work-experience, quitting, probation

My job is in the field I want to work in but not the actual job. I took it because of the pay, but realized it's not something I want to do. I'm still on probation but can't bring myself to tell someone that it's just not for me.

For some reason I feel afraid to tell someone. What should I do? Would I hurt someone's feeling if I tell them it's not for me? How many bridges would I burn? I feel like it's not me, so I want to quit but can't help but feeling afraid of quitting. If I do should I give 2 week's notice?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to workplace.SE! Sorry to hear about your situation. We'd like to help - however, the way you phrased the question is not a good fit for this site. You basically write "Here's my problem, what should I do?", which does not work here. You are asking at least three separate questions ("Will I burn bridges by quitting?", "How do I go about quitting?", "Should I give notice?"). Try sorting your feelings (possibly talk to someone you trust), to arrive at more concrete questions. Then ask them (separately), and we'll probably be able to help.

Comment: This is literally what the probation period is for; finding out whether you and the job/company are a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you what to do but it might be in your best interest to schedule a meeting with your supervisor to express your concerns. If after that, you're still convinced that the job isn't a good fit for you, only then should you consider quitting.  At the end of the day, everyone is responsible for their own happiness and if they feel offended or insulted, that's their problem.  As far as burning bridges, obviously this company isn't going to hire you back but it sounds like that won't be a problem for you as long as you're sure it's the right decision.

Edit: I should add that quitting a job after only a short period of time will not look good to future potential employers, so make sure you're prepared to answer questions about it.  "Why did you quit," "Why was it not a good fit," "How do we know you won't do the same thing again," etc.

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do? Would I hurt someones feeling if I tell them it's not for me?

You aren't going to hurt anyone's feelings - it's business.  They might not be super-pleased to hear you want to leave so quickly, but assuming they're professional about it, they should understand.  A good employer understands that happy employees are more efficient and generally easier to work with, so if they can't help you fit in, they at least shouldn't hold it against you that you're leaving.

This is what probationary periods are for, after all.  It's as much for you as an employee as it is for them as an employer.

> how many bridges would I burn?

Well, you definitely won't be able to come back here later, so make sure you're sure about that.  However, as long as you're honest and open about how you feel, and you give notice professionally, without whining or flip-flopping, I wouldn't call it "burning bridges."

> And if I do should i give 2 week notice?

**Absolutely.**  Always give appropriate notice.  Always.  Quitting without giving notice is more likely to burn bridges than quitting during your probation period because you're unhappy there.

You may also want to consider lining up a new job somewhere else before you quit this job.  Gives you a little more time to evaluate if you're really unhappy here.  Gives them a bit more of a breather before they need to re-enter the hiring process.  And, of course, prevents you from being unemployed for too long.

Comment: No you should give the noticed defined in the probationary period and I am not sure in the USA (with its 2 weeks notice) actually has legally defined probationary periods