# About to resign during my probation period, how do I go about it?

Tags: resignation, software-development

**Background:**
So I'm a software developer nearing the end of my probation period at a company I recently started at. After starting I noticed a few things that made the company not a very good fit for me. Mainly working almost exclusively on a legacy product, with very old web technologies, that was promised to me I shouldn't be spending much time on. Only the occasional bug fix but the product was basically EOL. Second, corporate policies like no working from home and/or abroad and having to clock in and out to measure your hours. After about two months I managed to get an interview via a contact at a company this contact was very happy at. They offered me a very competitive offer which would give me more freedom, working with new tech and a significant salary increase.

**Question:**
In the end I decided it would be for me to move since I'm not very happy about the current job. This opportunity came quite late in my trial period so I'm nearing the end and I'm a bit anxious on how to handle the resignation and how they will respond. Besides pulling my manager aside and breaking the news is there anything I can do or say to not burn any bridge (might not be possible) or to just handle things as best as possible?

Also feel pretty bad about having a gap on my resume now. Is this something I should be worried about or are the reasons outlined good if ever asked during a potential future interview?

Comment: Gap? Are you quitting before your next job?

Comment: A gap because of being at this company for like 2 months during this probabtion. And I'll be pretty much starting at the new place right after I resign. But that time I spent at this current company I'll have to leave it off I guess?

Comment: @CaptainObvious: there's nothing wrong with saying that you chose to leave a company during the probation period because it wasn't a good fit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm still on my probation period, but I don't feel that the job is right for me. Can I quit?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/99921/im-still-on-my-probation-period-but-i-dont-feel-that-the-job-is-right-for-me)

Comment: @Captain - Why would you leave those 2 months off your resume?  Did you not work there for 2 months?

Comment: 2 months is not a resume gap.

Comment: I did leave my company after 4 months. They were like "good luck with your gap", "what you did will end your career". Reality was different. I said to my new employer that I took my last job a bit too fast as an easy choice but as good as it could be it was not for me.

Answer (score 11):

> Besides pulling my manager apart and breaking the news is there
> anything I can do or say to not burn any bridge (might not be
> possible) or to just handle things as best as possible?

Just be honest and explain the lack of fit.

That's what probation periods are for.

Comment: I was going to say exactly this.  Probation periods are as much for you to evaluate the employer as they are for them to evaluate you.

Comment: Best answer so far. Probation are for the employer .. AND the employee !

Answer (score 3):

Unless this employer is very unreasonable, this shouldn't burn a bridge. You're still in your probation period so no promises have been made on either side.

> Also feel pretty bad about having a gap on my resume now.

You don't *have* to leave this job off of your resume unless you believe that this employer will give you a negative reference during background checks. You've probably seen the advice to "just leave it off your resume" in other questions about short term jobs but that's because those people also had to leave under fairly negative circumstances (a firing, harassment, etc.). They knew their employer was going to provide a negative reference and a short gap is better than a bad reference.

This is just a regular departure. Assuming it happens on good terms you can keep it on your resume. Note that your employer being *disappointed* you're leaving isn't the same as them being *angry*. If they're happy with you're work then they'll be upset it didn't work out but that by itself shouldn't lead you to keep it off your resume.

Comment: That's a very good point, I would assume that because I'm doing it towards they end they're not going to be happy about it. But get your point, all depends on how they'll respond of course.

Comment: Thing is a 2 month gap won't raise eye brows, its normal for people to just want some time off if they are financially good. So I'd consider leaving it off just to save space on the CV and avoid wasting 1-2 minutes of a future interview taking about it

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you notify the company before the probationary period ends. Some places require a longer notice period after the probationary period ends. In some places it might only be a couple of weeks, but in other places it can me one or more months. You don't want to miss the deadline and have to stay an extra month.

Because you are in the probationary period they may decide that when you tell them you are leaving that there is no need to work two more weeks. In other cases they still want you to stay a few weeks to finish up tasks.

There is no requirement to give a lot of details, just tell them you have decided to leave and that you want to talk about when your last day will be.

Regarding a gap in your resume. The resume is what you use to sell yourself. If the job doesn't help you do that, you don't have to include it. You might decide to include it if you are trying to avoid a gap. Or if even its presence does slow you to discuss some task you want to mention. Now if the application, or the background check forms asks you to list all jobs, then you have to mention it.

Comment: "In other cases they still want you to stay a few weeks to finish up tasks." That depends on where you are located. In many locations, one of the features of a probation period is the absence of a notification period (which works both ways).

Comment: The OP doesn't indicate their location, but in the U.S. at least they can't "require" any particular notice period - you can quit whenever you want.

Answer (score -2):

90% of what you've written in your question is unneeded. We don't need to know about your job, what you did or didn't do, what you liked or didn't like, why you're deciding to move on, etc.

How should you go about resigning? Like this:

"I've decided that I'd like to pursue other outside opportunities. Thank you for the opportunity."

How will they respond? Something like this:

"Thank you for letting us know about your decision. Best of luck to you in your future endeavors."

Comment: No reasonable employer will screw up the formal response. So the formal response does not tell you much about how they really think about the situation...